# How to export data from Cassandra cluster and import in another

Tags: cassandra

I want to export all data from a keyspace in a cassandra cluster and import it into another cluster, that has the same schema but the keyspace is differently named.

I've looked into the sstable2json /json2sstable utility. However, I don't want to go to each node and deal with each individual sstable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to export the data node by node, then you probably need to use the normal Thrift client interface to systematically read chunks of data from the source cluster and write them to the destination, working through all columnfamilies and their rows.  This may be relatively slow though.

Answer (score 10):

Simpler: take a snapshot on each node, then use the [bulk loader](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/bulk-loading) to stream them into the new cluster.

Comment: I didn't want to ask another duplicate question but with a slight difference, what if I also need to take the existing schema as well to the newly created cluster. I have created a new cluster, right now with no keyspaces or CFs or any data, I want to migrate entire data as well as schema to the new cluster. What are the good ways to do so ?

Comment: Use cli "show schema" command on the one cluster, and feed to the cli against the other.

Comment: We have cassandra 3 node cluster and we have replication factor as 3, is it possible to export data from cluster and import to single node (StandAlone server).